# problem in handling one-to-many and many-to-one mapping

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

the problem is when i add sous_categorie for a categorie that already exists an exception appears

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Le champ 'id_cat' ne peut être vide (null)

i used postman for testing the API

```
{
"id_Cat": "1274d819-ca54-455b-b69f-07a3f8b345c0",
"souCatName": "hospitals"
}
```

Class DBCategorie

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categorie")
public class DBCategorie {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
private String idCat;

private String catName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categorie")
private List<DBSousCategorie> souscategorie;

public DBCategorie() {
}
//getters& setter

public DBCategorie(String idCat, String catName, List<DBSousCategorie> souscategorie) {
    super();
    this.idCat = idCat;
    this.catName = catName;
    this.souscategorie = souscategorie;
}

public DBCategorie(String idCat, String catName) {
    this.idCat = idCat;
    this.catName = catName;
}
```

class DBSousCategorie

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "souscategorie")
public class DBSousCategorie {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
private String idSouCat;

private String souCatName;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id_Cat")
private DBCategorie categorie;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "souscategorie")
private List<DBFile> files;

public DBSousCategorie() {
}

//Getters & Setters

public DBSousCategorie(String idSouCat, String souCatName, DBCategorie categorie) {
    super();
    this.idSouCat = idSouCat;
    this.souCatName = souCatName;
    this.categorie = categorie;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the parent categorie object to sous_category before persisting ?

```
dbSousCategory.setCategory(categorie);
subCategoryService.save(dbSousCategory);
```

And to avoid recursion use @JsonIgnore to ignore the parent category.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "souscategorie")
public class DBSousCategorie {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
private String idSouCat;

private String souCatName;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id_Cat")
@JsonIgnore
private DBCategorie categorie;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "souscategorie")
private List<DBFile> files;

public DBSousCategorie() {
}

//Getters & Setters

public DBSousCategorie(String idSouCat, String souCatName, DBCategorie categorie) {
    super();
    this.idSouCat = idSouCat;
    this.souCatName = souCatName;
    this.categorie = categorie;
}
```

Comment: yes but when listing all the categories it caiuses an infinit loop

Comment: then try using @JsonIgnore to the parent category. ill edit the answer for that

Comment: there's no longer infinity loop but still the same problem for the id

Comment: can you add the controller and service code to the question to see more details